# Why current image is not coming in bitmap/image view in android OS versions 4.2 or higher?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am saving camera captured image to database and retrieving it from database. I am capturing it again and showing on image view so current image is shown in my android OS version 4.1..

same, is not working for samsung core having OS version 4.2..

please suggest any solution, as this is OS problem or some thing else

**on button click**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

**to set image on imageview,**

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {

                photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                Log.d("camera ---- > ", "" + data.getExtras().get("data"));

                img.setImageBitmap(photo);

            }
        }
    }
```

**to save to sqlite database,**

```
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
                parent.setImage(byteArray);
```

**to retrive it back from database and to show it..**

```
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
            Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            img.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

Comment: Where is your code ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: no error.. as soon as image get captured, it is showing previous image and not current image.. before saving to database..

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code ?

Comment: Who formatted this post..!? its horrible! Also this issue sounds like a state problem with your app.